# Geometric explanation of $\frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}\cdot x_1 + \frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1} \cdot x_2=x$

Tags: geometry

I'd like to know if there is a geometric interpretation involving the real number line to the following equation, under the context of $x_1 \lt x \lt x_2$:

> $\frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}\cdot x_1 + \frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1} \cdot x_2=x \quad (\dagger)$

I see that the fractions are ratios between distances (that add up to $1$), but it is not apparent to me why scaling each of those ratios by $x_1$ and $x_2$ brings us to precisely $x$. Obviously, if we work out the algebra, the statement is true - but I am lacking the intuition as to what features the algebra is describing.

This type of equation is frequently encountered in arguments involving convexity, so I assume its origin was not a random algebraic finding, but rather a geometry-guided observation.

---

The closest thing I have to offering geometric intuition is rewriting $x_1$ and $x_2$ as $x-(x-x_1)$ and $x+(x_2-x)$, respectively, which allows us to rewrite the left hand side of $(\dagger)$ as:

> $\frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}\cdot \big [x-(x-x_1) \big ]+\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1} \cdot \big [x+(x_2-x) \big]$

which we can rearrange as:

> $\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}(x_2-x)-\frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)+x\cdot \left[\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}+\frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}\right]$

I'm not sure if the commutativity of fractions is a particularly 'geometric' notion, but this attempt at rewriting seems, at least to me, to reveal why $(\dagger)$ is true. Basically, $(\dagger)$ appears to be reconstructing $x$ by decomposing $x_1$ and $x_2$ into components involving $x$.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Every point $x$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be written as a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) $x = \lambda x_1 + \mu x_2$ for some $\lambda,\mu \in [0,1]$ with $\lambda+\mu=1$. Solve that for $\lambda,\mu$ and you get your equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\underbrace{(x_2-x)x_1}_{\text{EFHG}}+\underbrace{(x-x_1)x_2}_{\text{ACFD}}=\underbrace{xx_2}_{\text{ACHO}}-\underbrace{xx_1}_{\text{DEGO}}$$

[image]